# SimpleXML PHP - Change Value from any Node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Normaly i find everything at stackoverflow what iam locking for. but now i need ur help.

my example xml:

```
<xml>
  <first>
    <change>Text to change</change>
  </first>
  <second>
    <change1>Text to change</change1>
    <change2>Text to change</change2>
    <change3>Text to change</change3>
  </second>
</xml>
```

Now i need to change the text from the change nodes. But this is a example xml. i dont know the structure from the xml. i only have the change names.
is there sth like in js `getElementsByTagName("change")`
what is to when i want to change the text from the change nodes

thanks guys... and sry for my english ;)

Comment: `first` and `second` as you're using them here don't belong in XML, as sibling nodes are unordered by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `xpath()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$changes = $xml->xpath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'change')]");
```

This will select all nodes starting with `change`. The `//` will select them from whatever position in the tree. The results are stored as `SimpleXML` elements in an array in `$changes`.

Now change the selected nodes:

```
foreach ($changes as $change) 
    $change[0] = "New Text";
```

Take a look at the changed XML:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

see it working: https://eval.in/231427

Comment: thx michi.. thats exactly what im locking for! :THUMPS UP: