# How to modify a XML node by attribute

Tags: php, simplexml

```
$xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<players>
    <string name="Paul">Foo</string>
    <string name="Peter">Bar</string>
</players>';

$xml = new SimpleXML($xmlStr);
```

How can I change Foo to Baobab in the SimpleXML object (without using a PHP loop) ?

Comment: have you red the SimpleXML doc ?

Comment: Yep. So I get the relevant node with an xpath - but the xpath returns an array, so it's useless to modify it.

Comment: I think this could help you, http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php on example #9

Comment: This has been asked before, a quick search for "replace value in simplexml" gives this page as the top result.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326066/simplexml-php-change-value-from-any-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use XPath as you say it returns an array.  As this is the first item you want to change you use `[0]`.

To update the value, you have to get SimpleXML to know you want to set the value of the element, the simplest way of doing this is to use (in this case) is `$foo[0]`.  Although `$foo` isn't an array, it fools SimpleXML into setting the value of the element rather than assigning a value to the variable called `$foo`.

```
$xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<players>
    <string name="Paul">Foo</string>
    <string name="Peter">Bar</string>
</players>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$foo = $xml->xpath('//string[@name="Paul"]')[0];
$foo[0] = 'Baobab';
echo $xml->asXML();
```

If you knew this was always going to be the layout of the XML, you could just do...

```
$xml->string[0] = 'Baobab';
```